# Facebook doesn't load CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, css, facebook, formatting

It seems facebook doesn't load the CSS/some JavaScript files because I see no formatting at all under Chrome.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12799551/fb.png

It also gives me several error messages:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12799551/fb2.png

It's not the first time though, it happened before, but back then I could somehow resolve it. I googled it and found it has something to do with the AdBlock extension, I turned it off and then on, I even added facebook.com as an exception to the list but still no luck. I'm using Windows 7 and Chrome 17.0.963.83. I hope you can help me as I don't want to use Safari anymore.

Thank you in advance,
Tamás

Comment: Have you tried removing the extension and then try?

Comment: Yes, I just tried it, still nothing. Wondering if noone else has this kind of problem.

Comment: Just verify once that all your css and js files are getting loaded properly.

Comment: refreshing the page should solve it.. your ISP does not cache the DNS entries..

Answer (score 4):

PeerBlock added Facebook style sheets / scripts on its blocklist at some point. Allowing HTTP traffic fixes this.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the time and date of your PC to the internet time. Don't know how it is related but it worked for me like a charm.

Comment: This. If you notice your PC time is not syncing with the internet (because your ISP blocks the default timeserver), change the timeserver to: pool.ntp.org

Comment: Brilliant solution. I wonder if Facebook does this for it's 'real-time' features and statistics. Anyone know more about this weird phenomenon.

Answer (score 1):

Go to chrome plugins , in your browser `chrome://plugins`

Disable some plugins like if you developed Java applications for cell phones,

```
Java(TM) - Version: 10.21.2.11 (Disabled)
Next Generation Java Plug-in 10.21.2 for Mozilla browsers
Name:   Java(TM) Platform SE 7 U21
Description:    Next Generation Java Plug-in 10.21.2 for Mozilla browsers
Version:    10.21.2.11
Location:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\plugin2\npjp2.dll
Type:   NPAPI
```

Sometimes it may interfere with desktop facebook rendering.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `dns` settings in your network adapter.
change them to `Google` `dns`:

`8.8.8.8`

`8.8.4.4`

and refresh the page. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

1. go to windows search bar.
2. search **Network and Sharing center**.
3. click your **connection name** which is display in blue color.
4. now click "**properties**".
5. in network section select "**Internet protocol version(TCP/IPv4)**"
6. after selecting click "**properties**".
7. make sure that "**obtain ip address automaticaly**" and "**obtain DNS server address automaticaly**" is **checked**.
8. Click apply button and exit.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this problem (all day today) and I looked at my computers date and time and sure enough it was off - so I changed it and the problem immediately resolved :)